# Variable size of map container filled completely with map (preferably in leaflet)

Tags: css, maps, leaflet, mapbox

I am making a responsive website and I have a map utility in it. The map container responds to changing screen sizes. I want to fill the map container div completely with map. Is this possible?

Eg. container sizes (width x height) - 10 x 50, 40 x 200, 800 x 100, 1500 x 200, 200 x 1600.

The problem is that raster map tiles come in squares (256 x 256, 512 x 512) - aspect ratio 1, and I am not so sure about vector tiles for crazy aspect ratios.

Would like to know, if the map pros out there have solved a similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: Resizing the Leaflet container should not distort the map tiles, vector or image, doesn't matter. It will just show more (or hide) tiles when resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Things (assuming leaflet.js is used) -

1. Define the size of map container in em, rem or px.
2. Call `map.invalidateSize()`, where 
   `var map= L.map("map_container_id", {center: [lat, lng]});` 
   once map has been loaded on to map container. 
   `map.invalidateSize()` [updates the map on change of size](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#map-invalidatesize).